# dhclient exits with status 0 but still no address

Tags: rhel, dhcp, exit

I've been trying to find out with the man page and some other sources if the exit status doesn't necessarily mean you achieved an address but I'm thinking I maybe didn't read it correctly. Does anyone know why dhclient would still exit with status 0 if it doesn't think I'm connected to a network? RHEL 6 seems to have some serious network issues.

Mostly I'm just confused as to whether or not I'm reading what the exit status is supposed to mean here.

I run 'dhclient eth0'
Nothing returns in stdout.
Yes where I am plugging in has DHCP set up correctly.

I should mention that if I pop in Fedora 13 live disc and drop to bash I can do the exact same steps and get on the network just fine. The *only* difference being that I used Fedora 13 rather than RHEL 6 disc.

Comment: Are you calling `dhclient` with any parameters? Is it emitting any output? Are you actually connected to a network with a DHCP server? Do you have a cached lease?

Comment: I just edited the main description but my only param is 'eth0.' There's no output. Yes, I know the network is setup with DHCP, when *not* using RHEL 6 (live-disc or otherwise) dhclient works just fine.

Comment: I have this same issue with a fresh install of RHEL6. What are we missing here?

Comment: Is NetworkManager running?  Is there a dhclient already managing eth0?

Comment: No we turn NM off almost as fast as we sign in the first time - gets in the way. No when I run dhclient on eth0 there isn't already a dhclient running it - I usually do it on boot and even if somehow it already had one I usually run a killall somewhere in there.

Comment: Will also mention that we're trying to *avoid* use of dhclient by default, but are merely trying to figure out why the network won't work with RHEL6, using either sysconfig scripts or dhclient I know how to have Fedora or RHEL under 6.0 running on the network in a few minutes, but 6 will not budge.

Answer (score 1):

Even with NetworkManager running, you can to use dhclient. Try killing dhclient and call it again:

```
# killall dhclient
# dhclient
```

If this doesn't help, you must see your network configuration, there are a lot of information about it in manpages (see 'man -k dhclient').

Anyway, this may help too: https://serverfault.com/questions/231076/configuring-dhcp-on-rhel-6

Comment: What does "dhclient -d" tell you?

Comment: -d forces dhclient to run in foreground, even when it has configured an interface

Comment: I meant -v, sorry. I was thinking of dhcpcd

Comment: from the manpage:
`       The  client  normally prints no output during its startup sequence.  It
       can be made to emit verbose messages displaying  the  startup  sequence
       events  until  it  has  acquired an address by supplying the -v command
       line argument.`

Answer (score 1):

from dhclient manual

```
   -1     Try once to get a lease.  One failure, exit with code 2.
```

this argument makes dhclient be more responsive over shell exit codes

Answer (score 0):

There might be a "hook script" running that is exiting with a status code 0 indicating to the main `dhcp3-server` program that all is well, but it really isn't.

On my Debian system the directories are `/etc/dhclient-enter-hooks.d` (intuition tells me here is to look) and `/etc/dhclient-exit-hooks.d`, don't know where'd they be for Red Hat.